# iptables - the meaning of "ERROR: No valid subcommand given"?

Tags: iptables

I've installed iptables on a embedded device with linux. I believe the installation was successful because all the other apps are working fine (busybox etc.).

I try to run them but i get the following error:

```
root@AlphaEdge:~ iptables -L
ERROR: No valid subcommand given.
Valid subcommands:
 * iptables-xml
 * xml
```

The only thing i found by googleing was this source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/iptables/+/android-cts-4.0.3_r1/iptables/xshared.c), which I'm trying to figure out simultaneously while waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my system (Ubuntu 13.04), `iptables` is a symlink to `xtables-multi`:

```
martin ~ # ll /sbin/iptables
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Feb 20  2013 /sbin/iptables -> xtables-multi*
```

All other `iptables` commands are symlinks too:

```
martin ~ # ll /sbin|grep xtables
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 Feb 20  2013 ip6tables -> xtables-multi*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 Feb 20  2013 ip6tables-restore -> xtables-multi*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 Feb 20  2013 ip6tables-save -> xtables-multi*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 Feb 20  2013 iptables -> xtables-multi*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 Feb 20  2013 iptables-restore -> xtables-multi*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 Feb 20  2013 iptables-save -> xtables-multi*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     86K Feb 20  2013 xtables-multi*
```

When you call one of these commands, `xtables-multi` uses the name it has been executed with to figure out which command you want to use. Calling `xtables-multi` directly (or calling it with a name that it doesn't know) produces the following output on my system:

```
martin ~ # xtables-multi 
ERROR: No valid subcommand given.
Valid subcommands:
 * iptables
 * main4
 * iptables-save
 * save4
 * iptables-restore
 * restore4
 * iptables-xml
 * xml
 * ip6tables
 * main6
 * ip6tables-save
 * save6
 * ip6tables-restore
 * restore6
```

The explanation therefore has to be that your `xtables-multi` binary hasn't been compiled with all available subcommands, and so it doesn't know what to do when you call it as `iptables`. You will probably have to recompile it with the correct options to get the `iptables` command working.